# Debug NSDocument app at startup via file drag-and-drop?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

Suppose I have an NSDocument app that supports dragging-and-dropping of a file onto its icon to launch the app and open that file. My NSApplicationDelegate has implemented

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename
```

which is invoked via the file drag-and-drop. I want to be able to break and begin debugging inside `application:openFile:` but must start the app out of Xcode to use drag-and-drop launching.

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xcode go to **Product > Edit Scheme** (or Option-Click the **Run** button in the toolbar).
Under the **Info** tab change the Launch option to

- *Wait for 'EXECUTABLE' to launch*

You'll want to set an appropriate breakpoint in your `application:openFile:` method,
then launch your app manually from the Finder by dropping a document file on the app icon.

To locate the built executable use '*Show in Finder*' for your .app in Xcode's **Project Navigator** (or CMD+1).

The Xcode debugger should attach and break in your method.

Comment: One further thing: you need to go to Product > Run before you manually launch your app from the Finder. Might be obvious to some people, but I missed that step.